# jQuery set Hash value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Prototype version

```
 var hash = new Hash();
 hash.set("date_query", "test");
 hash.set("date_search", "1");
```

Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have Hash tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jshashtable,](http://www.timdown.co.uk/jshashtable) a standalone JavaScript implementation of hash table. Disclaimer: I wrote it.